# How to retrieve a column's value in sparql

Tags: sparql

Ineed to retrieve a column's value once the query is executed. The query runs and gives me the correct answer in the Eclipse console. I need to just retrieve one of the attribute value from the row.
The Complete code is stored in SemanticSearch.java. This function is called from Admin.java.

```
public int searchForUser(String userName, String password)
{ 
  String prolog="PREFIX kb:<"+VUSER.getURI()+">"; 
  System.out.println("Search for user in semantic search.java"); 
  String queryString1=prolog 
    +"\n" +"SELECT interest " 
    +WHERE {?x kb:Uname ?username. ?x kb:Password ?password. ?x kb:Interest ?interest. "            
    +"FILTER regex(?username, \"" +userName +"\" )}"; 
  System.out.println(queryString1); 
  Query query=QueryFactory.create(queryString1); 
  QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
  ResultSet results1 = qexec.execSelect();

  //System.out.println(results1);
  //ResultSetFormatter.out(results1);
  ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results1,query);
  if(results1.getRowNumber()>0)
  {
    QuerySolution soln=results1.nextSolution();
    Literal RES=soln.getLiteral("Interest");
    String RES=results1.
    int res=results1.getRowNumber();
    System.out.println(RES);
    return res;
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

The Output is:

```
PREFIX kb:http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#

SELECT * WHERE {?x kb:Uname ?username. ?x kb:Password ?password. ?x kb:Interest ?interest. FILTER regex(?username, "anu" )}

| x | username | password | interest |
| kb:Anvika | "anu" | "anu" | "C language" |
```

After this error comes:

```
Feb 10, 2011 10:50:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE: 
Servlet.service() for servlet Admin threw exception java.util.NoSuchElementException: QueryIteratorCloseable
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.nextBinding(QueryIteratorBase.java:93) 
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.ResultSetStream.nextBinding(ResultSetStream.java:74) 
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.ResultSetStream.nextSolution(ResultSetStream.java:91)
at semanticsearch.SemanticSearch.searchForUser(SemanticSearch.java:126) 
at controller.Admin.doGet(Admin.java:84) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am not able to retrieve the value at a column.
Help.
Regards.

Comment: I have fixed the formatting of your code samples - please try and make them readable when you post them as it is very hard to help you if people can't understand your code

Comment: Duplicated at http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/3046/how-to-retrieve-a-columns-value-in-sparql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so then my next suspicion would be that you've tried to iterate past the end of the iterator. Using the condition results1.getRowNumber()>0 is a very bad idea since it is always going to be > 0 as far as I can tell (though this isn't clear from the Javadoc for ARQ).

Instead I would replace the condition with results1.hasNext() and see if that fixes it

*Redacted Original Answer*

<s>I suspect this is just a case of variable names being case sensitive.</s>

Replace the line:

```
Literal RES=soln.getLiteral("Interest");
```

With the line:

```
Literal RES=soln.getLiteral("interest");
```

And I suspect it will work fine.

Comment: No the error is in line that contains the code: QuerySolution soln=results1.next();

Comment: Do i need to import any specific library from ARQ.

Comment: I am sorry i did not know that stackoverflow.com and semanticoverflow.com are supported by the same set of programmers. I wanted urgent help so I was finding for the same for all the possible ways. I have posted the error in semanticoverflow.com. Sorry for the format of the code.

Comment: No need to apologise, many of the members on SemanticOverflow are also members here, asking a question on both will always ensure greater visibility for your question